# Eclipse Data Tools Project: SQL Query Parser - Imports fail to resolve

Tags: java, sql-server, parsing, eclipse-dtp

I am using Eclipse 4.5.1 Mars and the Data Tools Project is already integrated in this distribution. I am trying to use the SQL Query Parser of the Data Tools Project to parse a SQL-file. I created a new Java project, a package and a class and I used the code example given here: 
http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/dtp-sqldevtools-dev/msg00074.html

But I have trouble to resolve the required classes to use the parser. E.g. at the very beginning of the code you find this statement:
*SQLQueryParserManager parserManager = SQLQueryParserManagerProvider*
SQLQueryParserManager shows an error and asks to "Import 'SQLQueryParserManager ' (org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.query)" - which I do. At the import-statement section at the top of the java file "import org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.query.SQLQueryParserManager;" is the relevant reference. However, it keep on telling me that 'The import org.eclipse' can not be resolved.

I do not know anymore how to solve it. I tried to download the DTP and copied the plugins in the the plugin Folder of Mars but there was no change either.

Here is the .java-File that I try to run. It is pretty simple but still the required classes can not be resolved for some reasons. The classes should be part of eclipse Mars imo. I tried different Eclipse downloads and for all its the same. Please help

```
// imports needed
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.query.src.org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.query.SQLQueryParseResult;
import org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.query.src.org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.query.SQLQueryParserManager;
import org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.query.src.org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.query.SQLQueryParserManagerProvider;
import org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.src.org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.SQLParseErrorInfo;
import org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.src.org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.SQLParserException;
import org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.src.org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.SQLParserInternalException;

class LPGParserExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            // Create an instance the Parser Manager
            // SQLQueryParserManagerProvider.getInstance().getParserManager
            // returns the best compliant SQLQueryParserManager
            // supporting the SQL dialect of the database described by the given
            // database product information. In the code below null is passed
            // for both the database and version
            // in which case a generic parser is returned

            SQLQueryParserManager parserManager = SQLQueryParserManagerProvider
                    .getInstance().getParserManager(null, null);
            // Sample query
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1";
            // Parse
            SQLQueryParseResult parseResult = parserManager.parseQuery(sql);
            // Get the Query Model object from the result
            QueryStatement resultObject = parseResult.getQueryStatement();
            // Get the SQL text
            String parsedSQL = resultObject.getSQL();
            System.out.println(parsedSQL);

        } catch (SQLParserException spe) {
            // handle the syntax error
            System.out.println(spe.getMessage());
            List syntacticErrors = spe.getErrorInfoList();
            Iterator itr = syntacticErrors.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                SQLParseErrorInfo errorInfo = (SQLParseErrorInfo) itr.next();
                // Example usage of the SQLParseErrorInfo object
                // the error message
                String errorMessage = errorInfo.getParserErrorMessage();
                // the line numbers of error
                int errorLine = errorInfo.getLineNumberStart();
                int errorColumn = errorInfo.getColumnNumberStart();
            }
        } catch (SQLParserInternalException spie) {
            // handle the exception
            System.out.println(spie.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone please just integrate the file in his eclipse and tell me if the imports are getting resolved?

Comment: Can someone please just integrate the file in his eclipse and tell me if the imports are getting resolved?

Comment: hello? anyone able to help me?

Comment: hello? anyone able to help me?